# Magento API V2 wsi.xml file

Tags: magento-1.9, api, wsdl

I'm being driven mad by this wsi.xml file which doesn't seem to be doing what I'm asking of it. I'm creating my own API which does a bunch of things using a product's EAN (a custom attribute).

It works perfectly with a V1 API call, but isn't working for version 2 with or without WS-I compliance on.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
Namespace
    Eanapi
        etc
            api.xml
            config.xml
            wsdl.xml
            wsi.xml
        Model
            Api
                V2.php
            Api.php
```

Pretty straight forward.

The api.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <api>
        <resources>
            <eanapi translate="title" module="eanapi">
                <model>eanapi/api</model>
                <methods>
                    <specialprice translate="title" module="eanapi">
                        <title>Update Special Price by EAN</title>
                    </specialprice>
                </methods>
                <faults>
                    <data_invalid>
                        <code>100</code>
                        <message>Invaid Data</message>
                    </data_invalid>
                </faults>
            </eanapi>
        </resources>
        <v2>
            <resources_function_prefix>
                <eanapi>eanapi</eanapi>
            </resources_function_prefix>
        </v2>
        <resources_alias>
            <eanapi>eanapi</eanapi>
         </resources_alias>
    </api>
</config>
```

My wsdl.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
            <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        </schema>
    </types>
    <message name="eanapiApiSpecialpriceRequest">
        <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
        <part name="message" type="xsd:string" />
    </message>
    <message name="eanapiApiSpecialpriceResponse">
        <part name="result" type="xsd:string" />
    </message>
    <portType name="{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
        <operation name="eanapiApiSpecialprice">
            <documentation>Load product by EAN</documentation>
            <input message="typens:eanapiApiSpecialpriceRequest" />
            <output message="typens:eanapiApiSpecialpriceResponse" />
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding" type="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
        <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <operation name="eanapiApiSpecialprice">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:{{var wsdl.handler}}Action" />
            <input>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="{{var wsdl.name}}Service">
        <port name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Port" binding="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding">
            <soap:address location="{{var wsdl.url}}" />
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

And finally the wsi.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
     xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
     xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
     name="{{var wsdl.name}}"
     targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
            <xsd:complexType name="eanapiApiSpecialpriceEntity">
                <xsd:all>
                    <xsd:element name="ean" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" />
                </xsd:all>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="eanapiApiSpecialpriceRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="typens:eanapiApiSpecialpriceRequestParam" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="eanapiApiSpecialpriceResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="typens:eanapiApiSpecialpriceResponseParam" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="eanapiApiSpecialprice">
            <wsdl:documentation>Get product by Ean</wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input message="typens:eanapiApiSpecialpriceRequest" />
            <wsdl:output message="typens:eanapiApiSpecialpriceResponse" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding" type="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="eanapiApiSpecialprice">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="{{var wsdl.name}}Service">
        <wsdl:port name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Port" binding="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding">
            <soap:address location="{{var wsdl.url}}" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

**Edit:**

With WSI off I get an error saying: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [3] Invalid api path.`

I'm running the query with the following code:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magento.dev/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
$session_id = $client->login($user, $key);
$result = $client->eanapiApiSpecialprice(
    $session_id, 'test');

var_dump ($result);
```

With WSI compliance on I get an error saying: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Receiver] Unknown error in test.php:25`

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magento.dev/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
$session = $client->login(array('username' => $user, 'apiKey' => $key));
$sesion_id = $session->result;

$result = $client->eanapiApiSpecialprice(
    (object)array('sessionId' => $sesion_id,
    'ean' => 'test')
);

var_dump ($result);
```

Comment: just an educated guess: try adding namespace prefix to children of `xsd:schema`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @mam08ixo. Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: How much more specific can it get? In your wsi example, the child elements of `xsd:schema` (`complexType`, `all`, `element`) are missing the `xsd:` namespace prefix. As you did not explain what the error actually is (apart from _not doing what I'm asking_) I can only give that hint and not post an answer, sorry.

Comment: @mam08ixo, that clarified it perfectly, thanks. Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error: `Invalid api path`

Comment: Please update your question to include this error message. It might also be helpful to add the webservice call (code snip) that results in the given error.

Comment: @mam08ixo Thanks for your help, i've updated the ticket with the error and add the xsd: prefix as suggested (which didn't seem to have any affect).

Answer (score 0):

In most cases "Invalid api path" error means wrong value in < model > section of api.xml file or wrong Api method name using. From your api.xml file:

```
<v2>
    <resources_function_prefix>
       <eanapi>eanapi</eanapi>
    </resources_function_prefix>
</v2>
```

so first part of method name is "eanapi"

```
<methods>
   <specialprice translate="title" module="eanapi">
         <title>Update Special Price by EAN</title>
   </specialprice>
</methods>
```

second part is "Specialprice".
Try to call

```
$client->eanapiSpecialprice(...);
```

instead of

```
$client->eanapiApiSpecialprice(...);
```

You also can call

```
$client->getFunctions();
```

and receive all available method names for call.

Comment: Thanks @ToxsBes, unfortunately this post is almost a year old now so I've got no way of testing this any more. Hopefully your comment helps someone else though.

Comment: Yep, yesterday I have the same issue and solve it but dont find solution on SO. Thats why I put it here for others who will face in it in future.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code and found bug in file api.xml

Replace your code in fie api.xml

**From:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <api>
        <resources>
            <eanapi translate="title" module="eanapi">
                <model>eanapi/api</model>
                <methods>
                    <specialprice translate="title" module="eanapi">
                        <title>Update Special Price by EAN</title>
                    </specialprice>
                </methods>
                <faults>
                    <data_invalid>
                        <code>100</code>
                        <message>Invaid Data</message>
                    </data_invalid>
                </faults>
            </eanapi>
        </resources>
        <v2>
            <resources_function_prefix>
                <eanapi>eanapi</eanapi>
            </resources_function_prefix>
        </v2>
        <resources_alias>
            <eanapi>eanapi</eanapi>
         </resources_alias>
    </api>
</config>
```

**To:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <api>
        <resources>
            <eanapi translate="title" module="eanapi">
                <model>eanapi/api</model>
                <title>EAN API</title>
                <acl>eanapi</acl>
                <methods>
                    <specialprice translate="title" module="eanapi">
                        <title>Update Special Price by EAN</title>
                    </specialprice>
                </methods>
                <faults>
                    <data_invalid>
                        <code>100</code>
                        <message>Invaid Data</message>
                    </data_invalid>
                </faults>>
            </eanapi>
        </resources>
        <v2>
            <resources_function_prefix>
                <eanapi>eanapiApi</eanapi>
            </resources_function_prefix>
        </v2>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <eanapi translate="title" module="eanapi">
                     <title>EAN Api</title>
                     <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                     <specialprice translate="title" module="eanapi">
                        <title>Update Special Price by EAN</title>
                     </specialprice>
                </eanapi>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </api>
</config>
```

**Note:** Flush all cache in admin side & also assigned api roles to api user.

After check your v1 or v2 called.